# How to increase size of latitude and longitude numbers levelplot?

Tags: r

I am plotting a raster image in levelplot using R. since the sizes are small and not visible in pdf format I want to increase size of all written data.  I am able to increase the size of all written data except the numbers on the lat-lon lines. how do it do it so its visible?
code:

```
levelplot(temp1,margin=F,col.regions=my_colors,at=my.at, colorkey=list(at = my.at, labels = list(cex = 1)),
          main="Spatial plot",
          cex.main = 0.4,line = 1,
          xlab = list(label = "longitude (°E)", cex = 1.5), 
          ylab = list(label = "latitude (°N)", cex = 1.5),
          scales = list(cex.axis = 10))+
  latticeExtra::   layer(sp.polygons(SHP, lwd=2, col='black'))
```

Comment: You can add `scales = list(x = list(cex = 2), y = list(cex = 2.5))` to change the tick text sizing on a `levelplot`. If you need more of explanation, let me know. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).